# is it possible to reference a type via the name of a generic?

Tags: typescript

I have the following types:

```
export type DocumentType =
  | Item
  | List
  | User

export type DocumentInputType =
  | ItemInputType
  | ListInputType
  | UserInputType
```

and I'm trying to build something that takes the document type as a generic and is able to also figure out the input type without having to pass a second generic into the type. Is this possible?

```
type Documents<DocType extends DocumentType> = {
  data: DocType[]
  createDocument: (input: <<This is where I want the corresponding DocumentInputType>>) => void
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```js
type DocumentInputTypeOf<DocType extends DocumentType>
  = DocType extends Item ? ItemInputType
  : DocType extends List ? ListInputType
  :                        UserInputType

type Documents<DocType extends DocumentType> = {
  data: DocType[]
  createDocument: (input: DocumentInputTypeOf<DocType>) => void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write this:

```
export type DocumentsUnion =
  | {data: Item[], createDocument: (input: ItemInputType) => void}
  | {data: List[], createDocument: (input: ListInputType) => void}
  | {data: User[], createDocument: (input: UserInputType) => void}

// Item | List | User
export type DocumentType = DocumentsUnion['data'][number]

// ItemInputType | ListInputType | UserInputType
export type DocumentInputType = DocumentsUnion['createDocument'] extends infer F ? F extends (input: infer U) => void ? U : never : never

export type Documents<T extends DocumentType> = Extract<DocumentsUnion, {data: T[]}>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFcFtoTwgUwMYBsCGAndAXAlgPYB2AzgLABQeROimAZusoqAJK3SgDeoA1teABcoAOTtE0EQG5QAX0rVaDJiwAyeEjm58Bwkes3S5CmnUbNQAVRJ1t-IkNHW6R+VVPKL46KyIAHSBwAFTg-Fh57RzEOXwCcVxMlczUNHFjAkLC7XVEDNP9AhPcklSsbTHTg0PCdBz1nCoL4mTdKRAAPPwJMLRxq0AARAmQYRBoSSyJCIlAAXkpQUAAfbnBcdGFvAG0AXQAaUGRMRFxEIZHoMZxhAApqOM2YpszEAEo5gD5QADcCPHA3IsVlw1jgNqA8rsDkcTrRzqMaLd7oFhHlKi93rMvr9-oDlqt1sIGlDDsdTvDLojQHcmkTyujqpjsX8AZRKCA2Bx8Xl8Q02p1ur1+hSri85oNhgicBMpsQtiJQegRDstkQYAAjOg7NkUDneBlZFZo579FYNA2IfldHqgPpZEU0C3ih3SybTeUw8mSynxHagDq0BwkUDUei2ABioAA-KBIwGxuBgzSHiGiGHMFYmT8WdGrKBhEREN9bAWi3QdR1rUL7d6riQADxBf3tQOJiUXUXVL6zUAAURb2GQOHrLpl0wOIMJoCCu1kH0oQA)